# Typescript generic type bound to a function Vs Type bound to a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm a little confused with some generic behaviour in TS.
With this code in a d.ts file, with TS 4.0.2

```
type GetValueFn = <T>(obj: T) => number;
export const getAverageValue: <T>(input: T[], getValue: GetValueFn<T>) => number;
```

On the second line the compiler complains that GetValueFn type is not generic.

If i write it like that (notice the `<T>` moved from right side to left side of assignment on first line).

```
type GetValueFn<T> = (obj: T) => number;
export const getAverageValue: <T>(input: T[], getValue: GetValueFn<T>) => number;
```

The compiler is happy, i have a generic type.

Now, with this code :

```
type ComparatorFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;
type ElementGetFn<T> = (input: T[], comparator: ComparatorFn<T>) => T;
```

Written with the `<T>` on the left side.

If i try to use the types like this :

```
export const getMaxElement: ElementGetFn;
export const getMinElement: ElementGetFn;
```

This time TS complains that ElementGetFn requires 1 type argument (!?)

If i then rewrite the ElementGetFn declaration like this (with the `<T>` on the right side)

```
type ElementGetFn = <T>(input: T[], comparator: ComparatorFn<T>) => T;
```

Now the compiler is happy.

What am i missing ?